# Search Resources by Tag Name or Resource Name

Tags: mysql, ruby, search, ruby-on-rails-4, tags

I have created a Search using this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised). Everything is working great. I am able to search for all resources by name.

**How can I search resources by Name OR Tags with that name?**

**Ex:**

```
if I search for the word "Tutoring" in my text_field.

I should get all resources that contain the word "Tutoring" in the name, 
And all the resources that have the Tag "Tutoring".
```

I keep getting this error with my current code.

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous: 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `resources`.`id`) FROM `resources` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `resource_mappings` 
ON `resource_mappings`.`resource_id` = `resources`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN
`tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `resource_mappings`.`tag_id` WHERE (name like '%Tutoring%') 
AND (tags.name like '%Tutoring%')
```

Model

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :resource_mappings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :resource_mappings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags

end

class ResourceMapping < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :tag

end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :resource_mappings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :resources, through: : resource_mappings

end

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  def resources
    @resources ||= find_resources
  end

  def find_resources
    resources = Resource.order(:name)

    if name.present?

      ###each work independently, how can I combine these without getting the error above.
      resources = resources.where("name like ?", "%#{name}%")
      resources = resources.includes(:tags).where("tags.name like ?", "%#{name}%")

    end

    resources
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up using.

```
if name.present?    
  resources = resources.includes("tags").where("tags.name like :name OR resources.name like :name", {:name => "%#{name}%" })
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the attribute `name` is used in more than one table that you're trying to access. You'll want to add `table_name.` before `name` so it would look like `WHERE (table_name.name LIKE...)`. Just replace `table_name` with whichever table and field you're comparing the name to :-)